# Entity Framework Inheritance - Resolve Relations between entities with same parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

Here is my model

[image]

I need to map this model to Entity Framework, but my results are building only one table named Fluxo, and there are lots of ugly FKs.

Besides, I don't know how can I map my PK, defined at Fluxo class

Here is my mappings

```
public class FluxoPrincipalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoPrincipal>
    {
        public FluxoPrincipalMap()
        {

            HasRequired(f => f.CasoDeUso).WithOptional(c => c.FluxoPrincipal);    

        }
    }


public class FluxoAlternativoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoAlternativo>
    {
        public FluxoAlternativoMap()
        {
        }
    }

class FluxoDeExcecaoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoDeExcecao>
    {
        public FluxoDeExcecaoMap()
        {

        }
    }
```

UPDATE 1 - After Some Mapping Improvement

Ok, here is my new mappings

```
 public class FluxoPrincipalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoPrincipal>
    {
        public FluxoPrincipalMap()
        {

            ToTable(nameof(FluxoPrincipal));

            HasKey(x => x.FluxoId);
            Property(x => x.FluxoId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            HasRequired(f => f.CasoDeUso).WithOptional(c => c.FluxoPrincipal);

            Ignore(f => f.ValidationResult);
            Ignore(f => f.IsValid);
        }
    }

public class FluxoAlternativoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoAlternativo>
    {
        public FluxoAlternativoMap()
        {
            ToTable(nameof(FluxoAlternativo));

            HasKey(x => x.FluxoId);
            Property(x => x.FluxoId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            HasRequired(x => x.FluxoPrincipal)
                .WithMany(x => x.FluxosAlternativos)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.FluxoPrincipalId);

            Ignore(x => x.ValidationResult);
            Ignore(x => x.IsValid);
        }
    }

class FluxoDeExcecaoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoDeExcecao>
    {
        public FluxoDeExcecaoMap()
        {
            ToTable(nameof(FluxoDeExcecao));

            HasKey(x => x.FluxoId);
            Property(x => x.FluxoId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            HasRequired(x => x.FluxoPrincipal)
                .WithMany(x => x.FluxosDeExcecao)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.FluxoPrincipalId);

            Ignore(x => x.ValidationResult);
            Ignore(x => x.IsValid);
        }
    }
```

And here is my context config

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

            modelBuilder.Properties()
                // ReSharper disable once PossibleNullReferenceException
                .Where(p => p.Name == p.ReflectedType.Name + "Id")
                .Configure(p => p.IsKey());

            modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Configure(p => p.HasColumnType("varchar"));

            modelBuilder.Properties<string>()
                .Configure(p => p.HasMaxLength(100));

            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProjetoMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new RequisitoMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CasoDeUsoMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FluxoPrincipalMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FluxoAlternativoMap());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FluxoDeExcecaoMap());

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Comment: Does `FluxoPrincipalMap` inherit from `Fluxo`?

Comment: Yes... `FluxoPrincipal`, `FluxoAlternativo` and `FluxoDeExcecao` are 'Fluxo'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to work with inheritance in Entity Framework, you can see all of them here: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph

- [Table per Hierarchy (TPH):](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph) Enable polymorphism by denormalizing the
  SQL schema, and utilize a type discriminator column that holds type
  information.
- [Table per Type (TPT):](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) Represent "is a" (inheritance)
  relationships as "has a" (foreign key) relationships.
- [Table per
  Concrete class (TPC):](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines) Discard polymorphism and inheritance
  relationships completely from the SQL schema.

#### THP

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Fluxo> Fluxo { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}

public class FluxoPrincipalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoPrincipal>
{
    public FluxoPrincipalMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
    }
}


public class FluxoAlternativoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoAlternativo>
{
    public FluxoAlternativoMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
    }
}

class FluxoDeExcecaoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoDeExcecao>
{
    public FluxoDeExcecaoMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
    }
}
```

#### TPT

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FluxoPrincipal> FluxoPrincipal { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FluxoAlternativo> FluxoAlternativo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FluxoDeExcecao> FluxoDeExcecao { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}

public class FluxoPrincipalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoPrincipal>
{
    public FluxoPrincipalMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
    }
}


public class FluxoAlternativoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoAlternativo>
{
    public FluxoAlternativoMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
    }
}

class FluxoDeExcecaoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoDeExcecao>
{
    public FluxoDeExcecaoMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
    }
}
```

#### TPC

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FluxoPrincipal> FluxoPrincipal { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FluxoAlternativo> FluxoAlternativo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FluxoDeExcecao> FluxoDeExcecao { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}

public class FluxoPrincipalMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoPrincipal>
{
    public FluxoPrincipalMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
        Map(x => x.MapInheritedProperties());
    }
}


public class FluxoAlternativoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoAlternativo>
{
    public FluxoAlternativoMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
        Map(x => x.MapInheritedProperties());
    }
}

class FluxoDeExcecaoMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<FluxoDeExcecao>
{
    public FluxoDeExcecaoMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.FluxoID);
        Map(x => x.MapInheritedProperties());
    }
}
```